# Implement Facebook API login with reactjs

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, reactjs

I'm working on using Facebook's Javascript SDK for authentication. I've been able to import the SDK properly and put a Like button on my page. But, the facebook login button has to be wrapped in the tag:

```
<fb:login-button/>
```

I currently have all of the code from the [Facebook Login tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.2) pasted into my index.html, the only html file in my project, which houses the React application. But, I need to put the last part, which has the actual login button, into my React component. When I tried to do that, I got the following error:

```
ReactifyError: /Users/ritmatter/reps/js/components/Signup.jsx: Parse Error: Line 82: Unexpected end of input while parsing file: /Users/ritmatter/reps/js/components/Signup.jsx
sdk.js:61 The "fb-root" div has not been created, auto-creating
ping?client_id=894010190618709&domain=localhost&origin=1&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebo…:1 Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

How can I get the login button into react?

Comment: This video tutorial helped me on this https://youtu.be/9MhLHkf7Ifs

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I have figured out how to modify the Facebook tutorial for the Login API with ReactJS.

Firstly, in the react component where you want the Login link, include this code:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '<YOUR_APP_ID>',
      cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access
                        // the session
      xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
      version    : 'v2.1' // use version 2.1
    });

    // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call
    // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
    // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
    // the callback you provide.  They can be:
    //
    // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
    // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
    // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
    //    your app or not.
    //
    // These three cases are handled in the callback function.
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      this.statusChangeCallback(response);
    }.bind(this));
  }.bind(this);

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
},

// Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
// successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
testAPI: function() {
  console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
  FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
    'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
  });
},

// This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
statusChangeCallback: function(response) {
  console.log('statusChangeCallback');
  console.log(response);
  // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
  // app know the current login status of the person.
  // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
  // for FB.getLoginStatus().
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // Logged into your app and Facebook.
    this.testAPI();
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
      'into this app.';
  } else {
    // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
    // they are logged into this app or not.
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
    'into Facebook.';
  }
},

// This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
// Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
// code below.
checkLoginState: function() {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    this.statusChangeCallback(response);
  }.bind(this));
},

handleClick: function() {
  FB.login(this.checkLoginState());
},
```

Then, in your render method, make sure you have some HTML that will call that handleClick:

```
<a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick}>Login</a>
```

Note, this is the same code from the tutorial, but placed in a ReactJS component. The only difference is that you have to bind this strategically to make the Facebook API functions part of your react component. This login will finish with a response message parsed from the response given by FB.getLoginStatus(). You can also take the token out of that response object and send it to your backend for authentication with something like [passport-facebook-token](https://github.com/drudge/passport-facebook-token).

Comment: it's working but shouldn't you be doing the auth and stuff from the action creators?

Comment: I am getting: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined. Any idea? In you question you write "been able to import the SDK properly" do you need to do that and how? Thanks

Comment: @ChrisG. Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: @Shih-MinLee you make a good point, but I only mean to demonstrate a very stark example of ReactJS with the Facebook API. If you were building a more robust application with Flux architecture, then you would want to move a lot of this logic elsewhere

Comment: Hi user3430761. Nope I did not solve this. I use ES6 code and I am still getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined."

Comment: There is slight delay in display of facebook login button using this approach. I think loading of facebook api should be moved inside script tag after body.

Comment: I think there's an error : FB.login returns the loginStatus, but you ignore this callback and call getLoginStatus again.

Comment: Change FB. to window.FB.

Comment: It should be  `FB.login(this.checkLoginState);` , otherwise checkLoginState will be executed prematurely.

Comment: This does not work with the official fb login butotn https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button#configurator even though it works with a custom button as in the example. Any idea?

Answer (score 16):

I used Promises for Facebook Auth flow

**mixins/facebook.js**

```
const promises = {
    init: () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (typeof FB !== 'undefined') {
                resolve();
            } else {
                window.fbAsyncInit = () => {
                    FB.init({
                        appId      : '<app_id>',
                        cookie     : true, 
                        xfbml      : true,  
                        version    : 'v2.5'
                    });
                    resolve();
                };
                (function(d, s, id) {
                    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
                    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
            }
        });
    },
    checkLoginState: () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            FB.getLoginStatus((response) => {
                response.status === 'connected' ? resolve(response) : reject(response);
            });
        });
    },
    login: () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            FB.login((response) => {
                response.status === 'connected' ? resolve(response) : reject(response);
            });
        });
    },
    logout: () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            FB.logout((response) => {
                response.authResponse ? resolve(response) : reject(response);
            });
        });
    },
    fetch: () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            FB.api(
                '/me', 
                {fields: 'first_name, last_name, gender'},
                response => response.error ? reject(response) : resolve(response)
            );
        });
    }
}

export const Facebook = {
    doLogin() {
        this.setState({
            loading: true
        }, () => {
            promises.init()
                .then(
                    promises.checkLoginState,
                    error => { throw error; }
                )
                .then(
                    response => { this.setState({status: response.status}); },
                    promises.login
                )
                .then(
                    promises.fetch,
                    error => { throw error; }
                )
                .then(
                    response => { this.setState({loading: false, data: response, status: 'connected'}); },
                    error => { throw error; }
                )
                .catch((error) => { 
                    this.setState({loading: false, data: {}, status: 'unknown'});
                    console.warn(error); 
                });
        });
    },
    doLogout() {
        this.setState({
            loading: true
        }, () => {
            promises.init()
                .then(
                    promises.checkLoginState,
                    error => { throw error; }
                )
                .then(
                    promises.logout,
                    error => { this.setState({data: {}, status: 'unknown'}); }
                )
                .then(
                    response => { this.setState({loading: false, data: {}, status: 'unknown'}); },
                    error => { throw error; }
                )
                .catch(error => { 
                    this.setState({loading: false, data: {}, status: 'unknown'});
                    console.warn(error); 
                });
        });
    },
    checkStatus() {
        this.setState({
            loading: true
        }, () => {
            promises.init()
                .then(
                    promises.checkLoginState,
                    error => { throw error; }
                )
                .then(
                    response => { this.setState({status: response.status}); },
                    error => { throw error; }
                )
                .then(
                    promises.fetchUser,
                    error => { throw error; }
                )
                .then(
                    response => { this.setState({loading: false, data: response, status: 'connected'}); },
                    error => { throw error; }
                )
                .catch((error) => { 
                    this.setState({loading: false, data: {}, status: 'unknown'});
                    console.warn(error); 
                });
        });
    }
};
```

**Profile.jsx**

```
import {Facebook} from './mixins/Facebook.js';
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap';

const ProfileHandler = React.createClass({
    mixins: [Facebook],
    componentDidMount() {
        this.checkStatus();
    },
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            status: 'unknown',
            loading: false,
            data: {}
        };
    },
    render() {
        const loading = this.state.loading ? <p>Please wait, profile is loading ...</p> : null;
        const message = this.state.status === 'connected'
            ? (<div>
                Hi {data.name}!
                <Button onClick={this.doLogout}>Logout</Button>
              </div>)
            : (<Button onClick={this.doLogin}>Login</Button>);
        return (
            <div>
                {message}
                {loading}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Man, you saved me lots of time struggling this:))) I changed Facebook to Component though and all the references from global to "this" but your logic worked as magic!. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

ritmatter gave a good answer, but I'll show how I did this a little differently.  I wanted to use Facebook's login button rather than my own to trigger the callback for checking login state.  The login button might look like this:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" onlogin="checkLoginState" data-size="medium" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false"></div>
```

The button has an onlogin attribute, which the jsx parser doesn't support.  Using data-onlogin in the react fashion wasn't working, so I just added the button in componentDidMount:

```
        componentWillMount: function () {
                window['statusChangeCallback'] = this.statusChangeCallback;
                window['checkLoginState'] = this.checkLoginState;
        },
        componentDidMount: function () {
            var s = '<div class="fb-login-button" ' +
                'data-scope="public_profile,email" data-size="large" ' +
                'data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true" ' +
                'onlogin="checkLoginState"></div>';

            var div = document.getElementById('social-login-button-facebook')
            div.innerHTML = s;
        },
        componentWillUnmount: function () {
            delete window['statusChangeCallback'];
            delete window['checkLoginState'];
        },
        statusChangeCallback: function(response) {
           console.log(response);
        },
        // Callback for Facebook login button
        checkLoginState: function() {
            console.log('checking login state...');
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
               statusChangeCallback(response);
            });
        },
        render: function() {

            return (
                <div id='social-login-button-facebook'>

                </div>
            );
        }
```

All that's left to do is trigger the button upon mounting the component if you want to automatically call checkLoginState.

Answer (score 7):

I post my solution here, as the answers helped me to implement it, but the accepted answer from ritmatter did not work without the

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response)
```

statement from RubyFanatic's answer.
Furthermore the "onlogin" confused me a lot. It is simply not required in my eyes.

I want to share it, as this is a c&p solution, here my full code against fb api v2.8 (react-bootstrap can be kicked of course):

```
/* global FB*/
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Grid, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.checkLoginState = this.checkLoginState.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.testAPI = this.testAPI.bind(this);
    this.statusChangeCallback = this.statusChangeCallback.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : 'YOURAPIKEYHERE',
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.8'
      });
      FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
      FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
          this.checkLoginState();
        } else {
          console.log('---->User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
      }.bind(this));
    }.bind(this);

    // Load the SDK asynchronously
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js';
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  }

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
  testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome! Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
  }

  // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  statusChangeCallback(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      this.testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    } else {
      // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
      // they are logged into this app or not.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
      'into Facebook.';
    }
  }

  checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      this.statusChangeCallback(response);
    }.bind(this));
  }

  handleClick() {
    FB.login(this.checkLoginState());
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <main>
        <Grid fluid>
            <h1>
              Facebook Login
            </h1>
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
          <Row>
            <Col xs={12}>
              <a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick} onlogin={this.checkLoginState}>Login</a>
              <div id="status"></div>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Grid>
      </main>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution I used to get login callback. You can add this code for your Facebook login button in your **render** method:

```
<div className="fb-login-button" data-max-row="5" 
     data-size="large" 
     data-show-faces="false" 
     data-auto-logout-link="false" 
     href="javascript:void(0)">Login</div>
```

In your code, add these lines:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    // facebook signin  button render
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : 'replace with your app id here',
        cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access
        // the session
        xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
        version    : 'v2.1' // use version 2.1
      });

      // login callback implementation goes inside the function() { ... } block
      FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
        // example implementation
        if (response.authResponse) {
          console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
          FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
          });
        } else {
          console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
      });
    }.bind(this);

    // Load the SDK asynchronously
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  }
}
```

Calling **FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', callback_function)** during component initialization is important because that's basically your login callback. Checkout here for [FB.Event](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.7) documentation.

Comment: Thanks! @RubyFanatic This worked for me. But if I need to have the facebook SDK defined in all my components, so that if the user presses 'F5' and updates the page on a page which does not include the "Login" component, the facebook SDK is still defined. Do I need to the init code in all my components or is it a way to only initialize it once?

Answer (score 3):

I was recently working on **Facebook Login** for one of my project, So after going though many Stackoverflow answers and blog posts. I wrote a minimilastic code **using ES6 FatArrow Function Expression (excluding .bind(this))**. Hope this code helps you.

https://gist.github.com/ronit-mukherjee/3e933509643a4ab4e80452bb05c1a073

```js
/*global FB*/
import React, {
  Component
} from 'react';

class FacebookLoginButton extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
      }
      js = d.createElement(s);
      js.id = id;
      js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


    window.fbAsyncInit = () => {
      FB.init({
        appId: '9999999999999999', //Change with your Facebook app id
        autoLogAppEvents: true,
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v3.0'
      });

      FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', response => {
        if (response.authResponse) {
          this.checkLoginState();
        } else {
          console.log('[FacebookLoginButton] User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
      });
    };
  }

  checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      this.statusChangeCallback(response);
    }.bind(this));
  }

  login() {
    FB.login(this.checkLoginState(), {
      scope: 'email'
    });
  }

  statusChangeCallback(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      this.testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      console.log("[FacebookLoginButton] Person is logged into Facebook but not your app");
    } else {
      console.log("[FacebookLoginButton] Person is not logged into Facebook");
    }
  }

  testAPI() {
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('[FacebookLoginButton] Successful login for: ', response);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return ( <
      button className = "btn btn-block btn-fb"
      onClick = {
        () => this.login()
      } >
      <
      i className = "fa fa-facebook" / > Connect with Facebook <
      /button>
    )
  }
}

export default FacebookLoginButton;
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a mixin class to address this.

https://github.com/genxstylez/react-oauth-mixin

Answer (score 1):

This is by far the cleanest and simplest way I could think of if you want to use the button from FB instead of your own.

To use the button, it's as simple as this.

```
<FbLoginBtn
  width="250"
  dataScope="public_profile,email"
  onSuccess={callback}
  onFailure={optionalCallback}
  afterLogin={optionalCallback}
/>
```

This component is completely self-contained, and highly compostable because it doesn't rely on any external dependency nor does it have any predefined behavior other than rendering the FB login button.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class FbLoginBtn extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // post login behavior should be defined at a higher level
    this.onSuccess = this.props.onSuccess || (() => {});
    this.onFailure = this.props.onFailure || (() => {});
    this.onSuccess = this.onSuccess.bind(this);
    this.onFailure = this.onFailure.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // This is the meat of the component
    // create a script tag, load FB SDK
    // then after script is loaded, set related behavior
    // If you have other components that rely on the FB SDK
    // I recommend extracting this into its own module
    let self = this;
    let scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
    scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';
    scriptTag.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4&appId=xxxxx";
    scriptTag.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
      self.FB = window.FB;
      // I don't like exposing the SDK to global scope
      window.FB = null;

      // This subscribe the callback when login status change
      // Full list of events is here
      // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.9
      self.FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', self.onStatusChange.bind(self));
    });
    document.body.appendChild(scriptTag);
  }

  onStatusChange(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      const { accessToken } = response.authResponse;
      // I have a afterLogin optional callback
      // which takes care of ads landing, invitation or any other custom behavior
      this.onSuccess(accessToken, this.props.afterLogin);
    } else {
      this.onFailure();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div 
        className="fb-login-button" 
        data-width={this.props.width}
        data-max-rows="1"
        data-size="large"
        data-button-type="login_with"
        data-show-faces="false"
        data-auto-logout-link="true"
        data-use-continue-as="false"
        data-scope={this.props.dataScope}
      >
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default FbLoginBtn;
```

Comment: Thanks, really clean indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Might be late but @Zoreslav answer really help me a lot.
I just convert it to hooks so I can disable or add a loader at the fb login button while sdk is not loading.

```
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';

const initializeFb = () =>
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  new Promise((resolve, _reject) => {
    if (typeof FB !== 'undefined') {
      resolve();
    } else {
      // eslint-disable-next-line func-names
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
        FB.init({
          appId: 'APP ID HERE',
          cookie: true,
          xfbml: true,
          version: 'v2.8',
        });
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
        FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
        resolve();
      };

      // eslint-disable-next-line func-names
      (function(d, s, id) {
        let js;
        const fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {
          return;
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-const
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      })(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk');
    }
  });

const useFacebook = () => {
  const [fb, setFB] = useState([]);
  const [isReady, setReady] = useState(false);

  const initFacebook = useCallback(async () => {
    await initializeFb();
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    if (typeof FB !== 'undefined') {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
      setFB(FB);
      setReady(true);
    }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    initFacebook();
  }, [initFacebook]);

  return [fb, isReady];
};

export default useFacebook;
```

Then I can just re-use this at different component like this

```
const Login= ()=>{
    const [FBInstance, isReady] = useFacebook();
    return (<Button onClick()=>{
      FBInstance.getLoginStatus(resp=>{  console.log(resp) })
   }></Button>)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I extracted the code from the [react-facebook-login](https://github.com/keppelen/react-facebook-login) and updated it to use hooks.

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react'

const _extends = Object.assign || function (target) {
    for (let i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        const source = arguments[i]
        for (const key in source) {
            if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(source, key)) {
                target[key] = source[key]
            }
        }
    }
    return target
}

const useFacebook = function () {
    const appId = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FACEBOOK_APP_ID
    const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false)

    const facebook = {
        login: async () => {
            const {authResponse, status} = await new Promise(resolve => window.FB.login(resolve, {scope: 'public_profile,email'}))
            if (!authResponse) return {status}

            return new Promise(resolve => window.FB.api('/me', {locale: 'en_US', fields: 'name,email,picture'}, me => {
                _extends(me, authResponse)
                resolve(me)
            }))
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId,
                autoLogAppEvents: true,
                xfbml: true,
                version: 'v8.0'
            })
            setIsReady(true)
        };

        (function (d, s, id) {
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {
                setIsReady(true)
                return
            }

            const fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]
            const js = d.createElement(s)
            js.id = id
            js.src = `https://connect.facebook.net/en-US/sdk.js`
            js.async = true
            js.defer = true
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs)
        })(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')
    }, [])

    return [facebook, isReady]
}

export default useFacebook
```

How to use:

```
const [facebook, isFacebookReady] = useFacebook()

const handleFacebookLogin = async () => {
  const response = await facebook.login()
  console.log(response)
}

<button type='button' onClick={handleFacebookLogin} disabled={!isFacebookReady}>Login with Facebook</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this library:
https://github.com/keppelen/react-facebook-login

Works quite straightforward:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import FacebookLogin from 'react-facebook-login';

const responseFacebook = (response) => {
  console.log(response);
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <FacebookLogin
    appId="1088597931155576"
    autoLoad={true}
    callback={responseFacebook} />,
  document.getElementById('demo')
);
```

Comment: I tried this module , it is working perfectly while in desktop but callback function is not called while in mobile.

Comment: These default props has `disableMobileRedirect: false` and in the code there's a condition `(isMobile && !disableMobileRedirect)` to use http redirect or call `window.FB.login`.

Answer (score 0):

Find simplest code below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

import FacebookLogin from 'react-facebook-login';

import GoogleLogin from 'react-google-login';

class App extends Component {

render() {

const responseFacebook = (response) => {
console.log(response);
}

const responseGoogle = (response) => {
console.log(response);
}

return (
<div className="App">
<h1>LOGIN WITH FACEBOOK AND GOOGLE</h1>

<FacebookLogin
appId="" //APP ID NOT CREATED YET
fields="name,email,picture"
callback={responseFacebook}
/>
<br />
<br />

<GoogleLogin
clientId="" //CLIENTID NOT CREATED YET
buttonText="LOGIN WITH GOOGLE"
onSuccess={responseGoogle}
onFailure={responseGoogle}
/>

</div>
);
}
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler version of code that uses Facebook Javascript SDK for React (Function Components) Devs. Add this snippet to your function component and return a simple button pointing to `fblogin()`

For people willing to use `react-facebook-login` module, it does not work when we need more permissions than the default ones. It crashes the window after login. So as long as you're okay with a simple FB Auth integration, you can follow `react-facebook-login`, but if you need to get access to user's Instagram accounts via Graph API then probably this will help you.

***NOTE:*** This does not check the status of your login. You can add the extra snippet if you wish.

Include this in your `index.html` file

```
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

And in the component add this.

```
//declare a const
const FB = window.FB

async function fbLogin() {
await FB.init({
    appId: '<APP ID>',
    autoLogAppEvents: true,
    xfbml: true,
    version: 'v13.0'       
});

FB.login(function (response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
        FB.api('/me', function (response) {
            console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
            console.log('Complete response from Facebook', response)
            FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    let myaccesstoken = response.authResponse.accessToken
                    console.log('Access Token', myaccesstoken)
                }
            });
        });
    } else {
        console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
    }
// mention all your permissions here
}, { scope: 'public_profile,email,pages_show_list,instagram_basic' });
```

}

And then finally a button.

```
<button onClick={() => fbLogin()}>FB Login</button>
```