# Reacts Facebook login - using ES6

Tags: facebook, reactjs, facebook-javascript-sdk, babeljs

Having looked at this: [Implement Facebook API login with reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27717555/implement-facebook-api-login-with-reactjs)

I am trying to create a Reactjs component for Facebook login.

I am using ES6 and I keep getting: "Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined"

Code:

```
    'use strict';
import React from 'react';
import addons from 'react/addons'

export default class Login extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
      this.checkLoginState = this.checkLoginState.bind(this);
      this.statusChangeCallback = this.statusChangeCallback.bind(this);
      this.testAPI = this.testAPI.bind(this);

  }

  render() {
          return (
              <div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false"></div>
          );
  } // Render


  componentDidMount() {
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'xxx',
      cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access
                        // the session
      xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
      version    : 'v2.3' // use version 2.1
    });

    // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call
    // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
    // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
    // the callback you provide.  They can be:
    //
    // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
    // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
    // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
    //    your app or not.
    //
    // These three cases are handled in the callback function.
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      this.statusChangeCallback(response);
    }.bind(this));
  }.bind(this);

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
}

// Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
// successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
testAPI() {
  console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
  FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
    'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
  });
}

// This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
statusChangeCallback(response) {
  console.log('statusChangeCallback');
  console.log(response);
  // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
  // app know the current login status of the person.
  // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
  // for FB.getLoginStatus().
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // Logged into your app and Facebook.
    this.testAPI();
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
      'into this app.';
  } else {
    // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
    // they are logged into this app or not.
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
    'into Facebook.';
  }
}

// This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
// Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
// code below.
checkLoginState() {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    this.statusChangeCallback(response);
  }.bind(this));
}

handleClick() {
  FB.login(this.checkLoginState());
}


} // Component
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: add JSFiddle, show some code...

Comment: https://youtu.be/9MhLHkf7Ifs - This video explains the login functionality with codes provided for facebook, google and linkedin

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

**You have to add at least: `<script></script>` in your template, outside your component.**

This error is caused because the code trying to do something with `<script>` but he can't found it.

Answer (score -1):

On the second line of the code snippet below, the variable `fjs` is being initialized to an `undefined` value, which is then references in `fjs.parentNode`.

```
// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    // ... code ...
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```