# Facebook OAuth using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, oauth, reactjs

Is there any way to login with Facebook and get information by OAuth using ReactJS? I did it with JavaScript SDK, but haven't found any ways yet with React

Comment: That's how you do it, regardless of other tools you're using.

Comment: If you are looking for something like react packages, check [`react-native-facebook-login`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-facebook-login) or [`react-facebook-login`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-facebook-login) on NPM.

Answer (score 0):

I've also been searching for methods to do this properly. The only react component available is [react-facebook-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-facebook-login) and it doesn't play well with isomorphic applications.

So, because the isomorphic apps have different ways of rendering on the server side, I found that the only way available at present is to do it manually, to fit it in the application.

For client-only application, you can inspire from [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27717555/implement-facebook-api-login-with-reactjs/27724488#27724488).