# reactjs and Facebook API: Getting error 'FB' is not defined no-undef

Tags: facebook, reactjs, facebook-graph-api

I'm completely new in ReactJS and just wanted to play around and test some things out. I was looking into how to implement Facebook API, but getting this error message:

```
error  'FB' is not defined  no-undef
```

Wasn't sure how to go about fixing this. Would like to seek help to see what I'm doing wrong here. Am I supposed to import some kind of Facebook API?

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '123141151155', //random app number
        cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access
                          // the session
        xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
        version    : 'v2.3'
      });
      //JS SDK initialized, now you can use it
      FB.XFBML.parse();

      // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call
      // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
      // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
      // the callback you provide.  They can be:
      //
      // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
      // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
      // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
      //    your app or not.
      //
      // These three cases are handled in the callback function.
      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        this.statusChangeCallback(response);
      }.bind(this));
    }.bind(this);

    // Load the SDK asynchronously
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  }

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
  testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
      'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
  }

  // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
    // app know the current login status of the person.
    // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
    // for FB.getLoginStatus().
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      this.testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    } else {
      // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
      // they are logged into this app or not.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
      'into Facebook.';
    }
  }

  // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
  // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
  // code below.
  checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      this.statusChangeCallback(response);
    }.bind(this));
  }

  handleClick() {
    FB.login(this.checkLoginState());
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: If `FB` available globally? Otherwise it'll need to be imported/defined within this module.

Comment: @lux oh okay... I just searched for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fb, so i'll have to npm install fb and then import it similar to the document?

Comment: If that's in fact the same package, then yes, but I'd suggest looking at the `package.json` of the project you got this code from to be certain. Checking https://github.com/node-facebook/facebook-node-sdk, I'm not seeing a reference to the `init` method being used above, but I only did a cursory look.

Comment: shouldn't you require the module? `import FB from 'fb';`

Comment: @lux, oh I'm just building this off of my own new app (starting from scratch), so package.json is pretty much empty. I got the bulk of the code from another stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27717555/implement-facebook-api-login-with-reactjs

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca I think that's what I was missing, I just wasn't sure because I'm new to reactjs, but I think I'm starting to understand how it all works.

Comment: I'm almost sure you need to import the Lib, I was reading the official doc, I think that is what you are missing. All other code seems to be ok. Let me know if after adding the import you still have problems.

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca no errors came up after importing, thanks!

Comment: I will post the comment as an answer so it could be helpful to others. Would you mind to accept it and vote it up? Thanks

Answer (score 13):

I've encountered the same issue and come up with another solution.

`'FB' is not defined no-undef` can be solved by referencing it from `window`, namely using `window.FB` instead of just `FB`. This work around does not need to install any additional npm package.

Here is a working [repo](https://github.com/Jerryg6j3/react-fbsdk-example) of integrating the component into a React project, and in `src/App.js` you'll find the same code snippet above, and namely in the Stack Overflow question: [Implement Facebook API login with reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27717555/implement-facebook-api-login-with-reactjs?noredirect=1&lq=1)
.

Providing this alternative solution as an additional option and I hope it helps.

Comment: I was using Vue and webpack and this was the only thing that worked to pass that error screen, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score -3):

Accourding to the documentation, you are missing to import/require the lib. I think you just need to import the file at the begining like:

```
import FB from 'fb';
```

I Hope it helps